# Rearrange dataset with transactions per quarter info to transactional data with one column for each transaction

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I struggle finding a way to rearrange a dataset. The dataset has the following form:

**data**

```
a <- data.frame(Id = c("123Ba", "672Es"), 
                FirstFlight = c("1999-10-04","1999-10-05"), 
                EnrollmentMonth = c("1999-10","2000-10"), 
                Q1_1999 = c(3,0), 
                Q2_1999 = c(0,1), 
                Q3_1999 = c(0,1))

#     Id FirstFlight EnrollmentMonth Q1_1999 Q2_1999 Q3_1999 
#1 123Ba  1999-10-04         1999-10       3       0       0
#2 672Es  1999-10-05         2000-10       0       1       1
```

The variable Id is a unique identifier for each passanger and the last three variables represent quarters of a year (Q1_1999 = First Quarter in year 1999). The Value uf this Quarter variable indicates how many flights a person made in the respective quarter.

What I try to do is to reshape the dataset such that I get one row for each flight made by a passenger in a specific quarter. So for each entry in the Quarter variables the same number of rows should be produced and a new variable for the quarter needs to be added that allows to identify the quarter in which this single flight was made... I hope it got a bit clearer now.

**expected output**

```
b <- data.frame(Id = c("123Ba", "123Ba", "123Ba","672Es","672Es"), 
                Quarter = c("Q1_1999","Q1_1999","Q1_1999","Q2_1999", "Q3_1999"), 
                FirstFlight = c("1999-10-04","1999-10-04","1999-10-04","1999-10-05","1999-10-05" ), 
                EnrollmentMonth = c("1999-10","1999-10","1999-10","2000-10" ,"2000-10"))

#  Id    Quarter FirstFlight EnrollmentMonth
#1 123Ba Q1_1999  1999-10-04         1999-10
#2 123Ba Q1_1999  1999-10-04         1999-10
#3 123Ba Q1_1999  1999-10-04         1999-10
#4 672Es Q2_1999  1999-10-05         2000-10
#5 672Es Q3_1999  1999-10-05         2000-10
```

How to can I rearrange my data to get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
a$Quarter = apply(a, 1, function(x) toString(rep(names(x[4:6]), x[4:6])))
cSplit(setDT(a), 'Quarter', ',', 'long')[,-(4:6), with = F]

#      Id FirstFlight EnrollmentMonth Quarter
#1: 123Ba  1999-10-04         1999-10 Q1_1999
#2: 123Ba  1999-10-04         1999-10 Q1_1999
#3: 123Ba  1999-10-04         1999-10 Q1_1999
#4: 672Es  1999-10-05         2000-10 Q2_1999
#5: 672Es  1999-10-05         2000-10 Q3_1999
```

Answer (score 1):

```
q1= a[which(a$Q1_1999!=0),] #Select data for each quarter 
q2= a[which(a$Q2_1999!=0),] 
q3= a[which(a$Q3_1999!=0),]   

q1=q1[rep(row.names(q1),q1$Q1_1999),1:4] #repeat by number of flights
q1$Quarter='Q1_1999'  # Quarter Col. 
#do same for q2 and q3.
'''
'''    
final_data=rbind(q1,q2,q3)
```

This way u'll have row for every flights ,with quarter info in the col. To accumulate the data acc. to ID,just sort it.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Nice! but I think you can replace `seq_len` with `row.names(a)`

Comment: May be something like this `b = a[rep(row.names(a), a$Q1_1999+a$Q2_1999+a$Q3_1999), 1:3]; b$Quarter = paste(substr(b$FirstFlight, 1, 4), b$Id, sep = '.')`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar Thanks a lot for both inputs. This is almost what I needed but not exactly. I think there is a little misunderstanding what should be in the "Quarter" variable. It should show the variable name from the respective quarter or something similar where the year and the number of the quarter can be extracted from.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar : see updates made in the first post

Comment: @tgrueter : I have updated the solution.Hope it helps !